# Implementing OAUTH2 on an App Engine Project

Tags: django, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

I tried to add the OAUTH2 feature to my existing App Engine Application, but had some issues and I appreciate any suggestions.

Here are my steps:
1. To create a client ID in the Google Api Console, and crate a OAUTH flow;
2. Once users visit the `login` page, they will be redirected to the Google Login Page;
3. Once they agree the terms, users will be redirected to the landing page of my application

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id='my_client_id',
                           client_secret='my_client_secret',
                           scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
                           redirect_uri='http://www.example.com/')

def login(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_uri)

def ecoLandingPage(request):
    code=request.GET.get('code', '')
    if code:
        cred = "" + code
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(cred)
```

My questions are:

1. After a user is signed in and redirected to the landing page, if he refreshes the page, the following error appears, which I guess is related to `flow.step2_exchange(cred)`. Is there a way to fix this?

   INFO     2014-08-21 16:39:56,437 client.py:1304] Failed to retrieve access token: {

   "error" : "invalid_grant",

   "error_description" : "Invalid code."

   }
2. Also, since I am running a Django project on App Engine, what is the best approach to check the current user's information, since I would like to post their name on the right corner of my page. Any good examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OAuth can be a beast to manage. Personally I do what they do [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoUdWBzUZ-M) and use the decorator class. That way it will cover refreshes and many other beasts that show up.

To get the users information [user class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass) to get the users information. You can see it in action via their [Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingusers). You don't need to worry about the 'users.create_login_url' as theOAuth requires the log in anyways.

Comment: Great and I truly appreciate these links. Will check them out later.